# How to render asynchronously initialized components on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to ReactJS and have been seduced by the ease of implementing server-side rendering to reduce "time to first tweet". I'm running a Node-Express-React stack which pre-renders the markup on the server using React's renderComponentToString.

It works fine when the components can be rendered synchronously, however I'm struggling when it comes to implementing ajax-populated components (however this applies to any asynchronous operation during the initialization of the component, e.g. websocket).

Take the example from the React website: http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

```
componentDidMount: function() {
 $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
  var lastGist = result[0];
  this.setState({
    username: lastGist.user.login,
    lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
  });
}.bind(this));
```

It won't work on the server, since componentDidMount is never triggered when using renderComponentToString.
This simple case can be worked around by using the same HTTP request wrapper on the client and on the server (instead of using jQuery's $.get), and by pre-fetching the data before instantiating the component and passing it as a prop.

However, in an actual, complex app, asynchronous dependencies can get very complicated and pre-fetching doesn't really fit the descendant approach of building React structures. 
How can I implement an asynchronous initialization pattern in React that can be rendered on the server without actually mounting anything (i.e. no DOM emulation a la PhantomJS, which is the whole point of using renderComponentToString) ?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the most practical way to do this is to make an optional prop for the preloaded data, like so:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    if (this.props.initialLastGist) {
        var lastGist = this.props.initialLastGist;
        return {
            username: lastGist.user.login,
            lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
        };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    if (!this.props.initialLastGist) {
        $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
            var lastGist = result[0];
            this.setState({
                username: lastGist.user.login,
                lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }
},
```

With a setup like this, the component can be rendered immediately if the preloaded data is present; otherwise the AJAX request will be sent while mounting.

Currently, server rendering is always synchronous and `componentDidMount` isn't called on the server because it usually involves DOM manipulation. Sorry I don't have a better solution here right now, but in general you want to minimize the number of HTTP requests to the server so it's worth thinking through your architecture so that you can collect all the data you need on the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the "HTTP" part of this is not my main problem, the problem is the same for any asynchronous operation involved in initialing the components, e.g. database query (in my current setup database queries are delegated to a second server which implements an HTTP REST api for historical reasons). My goal is to somehow mark the component as "only partially initialized", wait until the initialization of all the components is complete, recursively (i.e. new components induced are also completely initialized), and then only call renderComponentToString.

Comment: I understand. Currently, renderComponentToString always operates synchronously so there's no easy way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Great way to do this without having to include an extra external library like `react-async`. This works perfectly for any async ops -- my application is not using AJAX but is using PostMessage. This was an elegant, easy solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the [react-quickstart](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-quickstart) project, which uses `react-async` and ships with a server-rendering example. `react-async` provides a decorated `renderComponentToString` method that pre-fetches asynchronous state and renders it into the initial markup. However, you will need to specify asynchronous state separately from 'regular' state.

Comment: `react-async` is broken with the latest version of react. do you know any other alternative to `react-async`

Answer (score 0):

you can check out react-nexus (https://github.com/elierotenberg/react-nexus) which helps you declare all your async dependencies ahead of time.

but I realize that react-nexus is your own answer to this problem so you probably already found it !